# Is it possible to add a single executable, rather than an entire directory, to my $PATH?

Tags: path

I have XAMPP installed in OSX, and by default it prepends the path to its own `bin` directory (full of various utilities) to my `$PATH` variable:

```
# Add path to XAMPP PHP version
export XAMPP_PHP=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
export PATH="$XAMPP_PHP:$PATH"
```

Rather unfortunately, one of its utilities is called `HEAD`, which thanks to OSX's case-insensitive filesystem, [collides with the Unix `head` command](https://superuser.com/a/664166/378833).  XAMPP's `HEAD` is completely unrelated to `head` (I think it issues an HTTP HEAD request).

Of course, I want to use both `head` and XAMPP, so I simply changed the path variable order:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$XAMPP_PHP"
```

This lets me use `head`, but now there is a collision between XAMPP's version of PHP (for example, 5.5), and the preinstalled version of PHP that comes with OSX (5.3).  Since the path to 5.3 comes first, it ends up taking precedence.

My plan for a hackish solution was to prepend *the full file path+name just XAMPP's version of PHP*, then append the rest of the path after `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php:$PATH:$XAMPP_PHP"
```

This does not seem to work.  When I restart bash and check `php -v`, it's still on PHP 5.3 - the built-in version.  Is it even possible to add a specific file path to `$PATH` at all?

Comment: No, `$PATH` may consist only of directories.  You could simply symlink the particular executable you want into an existing directory in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that `echo "$PATH"` shows `/usr/local/bin` in your path, and given that this is your personal laptop:

Create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` that points to the executable you want.

```
ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

If it is a shared computer and you don't want to affect other users, I recommend setting up a custom extension to your PATH in `~/.bash_profile`.  I have one myself:

```
$ grep PATH ~/.bash_profile 
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.bin"
```

Then I can put my custom symlinks, scripts, etc. in `~/.bin` and they will run as expected (without overriding system commands that exist earlier in my PATH).

I put the `.` at the start of `.bin` so I don't have to see the directory when browsing in Finder.